# golf mk1 1990 clutch problem

Tags: clutch, golf

I was driving my golf and the clutch pedal was creaking a bit but working ok, suddenly i pushed the pedal down it clicked and went to the floor i got recovered and the mechanic showed me the cable coming through the bulkhead splitting the metal around it. I repaired the metalwork but went to reatach the cable but the clutch cable doesnt pull enough to work and wants to pull the cable through the bulkhead again,any ideas why this would do that

Comment: Cables can fail through stretching or shrinking, and the failure can be rather sudden. Are you confident that the clutch cable length is what it should be?

Comment: Not sure it was working fine till it came through the bulkhead but it seems too short now

Comment: If that is the case then the cable has probably bunched up (I've seen this happen on window regulator cables a lot). The cable will need replacing

Comment: Ok i'll check the length , it is pulling and returning the arm on the casing but doesnt seem to pull long enough

Comment: @SteveMatthews knows his way around Mk1 Golfs. His answer will best reflect your situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a common problem on the Mk1 that the clutch cable pulls through the bulkhead and the repair plate is usually all that is required, however you may find that this no longer gives you enough travel on the cable.

Undo the two interlocking nuts on the gearbox end of the cable and remove them completely.  Thread the table through the fork split in the release arm and reassemble tightening only until the cable is tight against the arm.

Try the clutch pedal and see where the bite point is.  You can adjust these two nuts to move the bite point around under your left foot.

If it seems that the cable is trying to split the bulkhead again, it may be that you've fitted an inferior quality strengthening plate.  The ones I've fitted have been the stick on types that attach over the original bulkhead metalwork.

Comment: Ok i tried a different method of repair i reshaped the metal and used chemical metal both sides it fixed ok but the cable seems too short and getting the pedal back on leaves no pull on the cable

Comment: I'd be surprised if chemical metal holds for more than a few weeks.  It may be that your repair has forced the sheath of the cable to sit more proud than it usually would this shortening the effective length of the cable.  If it were my Mk1, I'd spend a few quid on the correct panel. https://www.vwheritage.com/shop/171898152/bulkhead-repair-patch-for-clutch-cable-mk1-golf-jetta-sciro/

Comment: The repair seems ok i got it back to shape easily, could there be something wrong with the cable or clutch itself

Comment: It is very unlikely that there is an issue with the clutch itself.  The movement of the air is fairly small and limited by the bellhousing.  It could be that the cable has stretched of the end of the sheath has deformed but again this is unlikely with the behaviour you describe.